# something with .change in jQuery going wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

I've got this odd problem with jQuery. I'm trying to let the change of an html select, trigger a post to a .php that returns new replacement html data for another select element.
I succeed in replacing the select html with just the post part, but when I add the .change part it stops working.

Here's my test page html(it's a .php page)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
        <title></title>
        </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>

        <select id=control6>
            <option selected="selected" value="normal">normal</option>
            <option value="change">change</option>
        </select>

        <select id=sortedselect6>
            <option selected="selected" value="alphabetic">alphabetic</option>
            <option value="grammatic">grammatic</option>
            <option value="assessment">assessment</option>
            <option value="maximatch">maximatch</option>
        </select>

        <select id=dummyselect6>
            <option selected="selected" value="dummy1">dummy1</option>
            <option value="dummy2">dummy2</option>
        </select>

    </body>
</html>​
```

the ajax.js

```
jQuery("select#control6").change(function() {
    jQuery.post('verwerker.php', {
        currentselect: jQuery("select#control6").val()
    }, function(htmldata) {
        jQuery("select#sortedselect6").html(htmldata);
    });
});​
```

verwerker.php

```
<?php
echo '<option value="alphabetic">alphabetic</option>
<option selected="selected" value="grammatic">grammatic</option>
<option value="assessment">assessment</option>
<option value="maximatch">maximatch</option>';
?>
```

Now if I only put the following in ajax.js then it changes the sortedselect6 to grammatic as selected instantly. So it must be something with the .change part that messes up?

```
jQuery.post('verwerker.php', {
    currentselect: jQuery("select#control6").val()
}, function(htmldata) {
    jQuery("select#sortedselect6").html(htmldata);
});​
```

You can view the last piece of code (the one without the .change) at work here http://www.tarile.net63.net/thebirdistheword.php

P.S.: the {currentselect:jQuery("select#control6").val()} is for later, it has no purpose right now

**Solved! The problem was that my jQuery couldn't load some of the elements because the page wasn't yet fully loaded. Damn I feel really dumb to have made that mistake, really dumb. xD here's the fixed code:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#sortedselect6").change(function() {
        jQuery.post('verwerker.php',{selection:jQuery("select#control6").val()}, function(newSelectdata) {
        jQuery("select#sortedselect6").html(newSelectdata);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic change and ajax code works fine in this jsfiddle. Note that data is slightly different simply due to fiddle requires you to send the actual html in order to test ajax

http://jsfiddle.net/up6fG/

Make sure you are wrapping your code in ready event so that the elements exist when code fires

```
    $(function(){
     /* your code here*/

    })
```

Comment: I've been testing with your link, when I change the /echo/html/ to the actual path to my site, it stops working

Comment: I'll try out your wrap suggestion

Comment: This is yours http://jsfiddle.net/KHQwY/
this is mine http://jsfiddle.net/xQneN/
It seems it has something to do with the loading of the item?

Comment: you can't make a cross domain request unless it is jsonp data format

Comment: my bad, actually read about that in my book, anyhow [link](http://www.tarile.net63.net/thebirdistheword.php) shows how the second piece of code(without the .change) works normally

Comment: ah **** I'm getting all confused, hold on

Comment: it is only working because ajax takes time to complete... by time it is complete the element you place results in exists. You need to wrap code as I've shown to make change event work

Comment: so wait I'm .ready'ing the document as a whole or the verwerker.php?

Comment: you are making sure selectors in jQuery exist before the code fires that looks for them. If they don't exist when code fires nothing will happen.

Comment: Thank you so much! Finaly I can move on from that blatant mistake >.< If you upvote my question I'll have 15+ rep and be able to upvote your answer =)